# How do I store a variable outside of loops

Tags: php

I have got a problem with the variable outside the loops. I want to store the variable of `$programme_title` from the `foreach $time_arr` loop shown below, and get back a short list of strings like this:

```
Paid Programming The Mentalist - Black HeartsAnthony Bourdain Parts Unknown - Russia
NFL Live StosselBad Dog! - Bad to the BoneHouse - Son of Coma GuyCutlery Corner Wild
The Real Housewives of Atlanta - Secrets RevealedThe Real Housewives of Atlanta - Secrets Revealed
The Real Housewives of Atlanta - Secrets Revealed The Real Housewives of Atlanta - Secrets Revealed 
The Real Housewives of Atlanta - Secrets Revealed The Real Housewives of Atlanta - Secrets Revealed
The Real Housewives of Atlanta - Secrets RevealedThe Real Housewives of Atlanta - Secrets Revealed
```

When I used this code:

```
 foreach($programme_arr as $programme)
  {
    $programme1 = $programme->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $programme_title = $programme1;
  }
  echo $programme_title;
```

Or try this:

```
foreach($programme_arr as $programme)
{
  $programme1 = $programme->item(0)->nodeValue;
  $programme_title = $programme1;
}


foreach($time_arr as $time)
{
   echo $programme_title;
}
```

It doesn't work. So, I tried this code:

```
foreach($programme_arr as $programme)
{
  $programme1 = $programme->item(0)->nodeValue;
  $programme_title = $programme1;
  echo $programme_title;
}
```

And got back this large list of string:

```
    Step Up 3The 700 Club The Fresh Prince of Bel-Air - Not With My Cousin You Don't
The Fresh Prince of Bel-Air - Viva Lost Wages The Fresh Prince of Bel-Air - There's the Rub
The Fresh Prince of Bel-Air - There's the RubSummer Sexy With T25!Dr. Ordon's Secret!
The 700 ClubAirbrushed BeautySleep Better!Joseph PrinceLife Today With James Robison - SMF Special 1
Joyce Meyer: Enjoying Everyday LifeShaun T's Focus T25That '70s Show - The Velvet Rope
That '70s Show - Laurie and the ProfessorThat '70s Show - HalloweenThat '70s Show - Van Stock
```

and so on...

Can you please tell me how I can store the variable of `$programme_title` in the `foreach $time_arr` to allow me to print the list of strings like on above?

Comment: yes I can, but I tried to use something is like `$programme_title = array($programme->item(0)->NodeValue);` I will get the input something is like `ArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArray`. Do you have any idea how I can use the variable of `$programme_title` with array?

Comment: What do you want to save to `$time_arr`? All of the lines of `$programme_arr`? It's really unclear what you are trying to do. Don't you have a little backstory or clearer explanation for this problem?

Comment: @TomKriek yes I want to use the $programme_title under the $time_arr loop because I'm creating the variable of $xml so I can store the $programme_title in the $xml variable. And yes I want to get all of the lines of the $programme_arr to allow me to store the variable $programme_title under the foreach $time_arr. how i can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with variable scope. Your variable has to exist outside the loop if you want to access it when the loop is comple. If you do this:

```
$programme_title = NULL;
foreach($programme_arr as $programme) {
    $programme1 = $programme->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $programme_title = $programme1;
}

echo $programme_title;
```

You will echo the title of the last item in `$programme_arr`. If you want to get all the titles, need to put them in an array:

```
$titles = array();
foreach($programme_arr as $programme) {
    $programme1 = $programme->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $titles[] = $programme1;
}

print_r($titles);
```